# android EROFS in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to read some files and put them into a new file using the below method in Eclipse.
But I am getting a read-only file system EROFS error in eclipse at run time.

Input file names will be provided as function parameter. Files are present in res\raw folder.

SampleFile.mp3 is an empty audio file placed at the location.

```
  public void myfun(Set s)
    {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(".\\res\raw\sampleFile.mp3",true);
        FileInputStream fis;
        Iterator ptr=s.iterator();
        String str;
        while(ptr.hasNext()!=null)
        {
            str=ptr.next().toString();
            fis=new FileInputStream(str);
            int i;

                while((i=fis.read())!=-1)
                {
                    fos.write(i);
                }

            fis.close();
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write into the 'res/raw' folder of the current directory, but android does not work like that. Go read the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) section of the Android Development Guide, and choose one that fits your needs (and use case).

Also, you want to concatenate multiple files into an mp3? Are they by any chance... mp3 files themselves that you want to play?

Comment: hi,
I want to combine different .wav files into one file. I have created a blank .wav file and placed at res/raw folder. But when trying to open the .wav file, it gives this error

Comment: In what way do you want to combine them? Play them one after another? Play them simultaneously? You can't do that in the way you described for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: I am passing a set to the myFun() method which contains the names of the files which I want to combine in one mp3/wav file.
I want to play them one after another. 
Set should be iterated and append into the output file. I can use any audio format mp3/wav in my application.
Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Are you by any chance writing a sequencer? If not, why do you want to concatenate sounds? Do you want to play them one after another?

Comment: actually I am trying to develop a speech synthesis for an Indian language.. For that I have recorded the sound files. So to play a word , I need to combine different sound files. So playing them one after another would also work. But it would be great if those files can be combined into one and then played.

Comment: is there any way I can achieve so ?